# Let's Encrypt validation under cPanel getting a 404 error after www redirect

Tags: cpanel, security-certificate, lets-encrypt

I'm having some problems getting the SSL via Let's Encrypt working on my site. I installed the certificate via a one-click installer in my cpanel. It works on my cPanel, but on the actual site it doesn't.

The only errors I've found are at `cPanel-->Security-->SSL/TLS Status-->Certificate Status`. I'm getting the following error:

> The system queried for a temporary file at
>   “http://www.example.com/.well-known/pki-validation/6A1D6A71FCF2BB1068FF69CDBB8B4A2E.txt”,
>   which was redirected from
>   “http://example.com/.well-known/pki-validation/6A1D6A71FCF2BB1068FF69CDBB8B4A2E.txt”.
>   The web server responded with the following error: 404 (Not Found). A
>   DNS (Domain Name System) or web server misconfiguration may exist. The
>   domain “example.com” resolved to an IP address “192.64.119.244” that
>   does not exist on this server.

I've done some checking and there doesn't seem to be any files in the directory `http://www.example.com/.well-known/pki-validation/` I'm not sure what to do to resolve this. I've tried removing the .htaccess file and that didn't help.

Comment: The files that are created during the validation process are temporary and are usually removed immediately.   It isn't unusual not to have them around after you get an error such as that.

Comment: Is that IP address the expected IP address for your server?

Comment: The SSL was generated, and installed via a one click installer in my cpanel. As far as the IP address, it doesn't match anything, anywhere that I can find.

Comment: Just had a thought. I just recently transfered my domain into the current Host, but waited until the domain was resolving correctly to install the cert. Is it possible that there were still some DNS records that hadn't updated somewhere, and messed it up?

Comment: "transfered my domain into the current Host" - That could be the problem. But what do you mean exactly by "transferred"? You changed _registrar_? You changed NAMESERVERS? You changed A records? That IP address is owned by "Namecheap" - does that ring any bells?

Comment: Yes. I had the domain parked at namecheap. Then purchased hosting at my current Host. I waited until it was  resolving to my current Host and I could access my site properlylto install the security cert.